# array_search don't start at 0

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system

first sorry for my bad english (Swissguy).
I want make a simple Template Script that search in Template Panelgroups and replace it with Content

My problem is on the line 20 with array_search.

```
include 'config/config.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$sql_1 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM office_template_placeholder");
while($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_object($sql_1)){
    $panelgroup[] = $row_1->name;
}
$sql_2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM office_content");
while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_2)){
    $panel_panelgroup[] = $row_2[panelgroup];
    $panel_source[] = $row_2[source];
}
if( $source = @file_get_contents( "design.html" )) {
    foreach( $panelgroup as $key => $var ){
        $position = array_search($var, $panel_panelgroup); //Starts with key = 1 but i need key number 0
        if($var == $panel_panelgroup[$position]){
            $source = str_replace( "{".$var."}", $panel_source[$position], $source );
        }
    }
}
echo $source;
```

Comment: Try [`reset($panel_panelgroup)`](http://php.net/reset) the internal array pointer before you `array_search()`.

Comment: it does not work. It does not change anything.